# ASP.NET MVC 3 - Dependency Resolver Issue When Replacing the Common Service Locator

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, dependency-injection, unity-container, service-locator

Using Microsoft Unity i register the following type:

```
container.RegisterType(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(NHibernateRepository<>));
```

In ASP.NET MVC 2 i could then do the following:

```
var repository = ServiceLocator.Current
    .GetInstance(typeof(IRepository<>).MakeGenericType(bindingContext.ModelType));
```

But in version 3. I have removed all occurances of the Service Locator and implemented the new Dependency Resolver instead. Therefore i changed the above to:

```
var repository = DependencyResolver.Current
    .GetService(typeof(IRepository<>).MakeGenericType(bindingContext.ModelType));
```

However this now returns null.

Here is my implementation of the Dependency Resolver if it helps:

```
public class UnityDependencyResolver : IDependencyResolver {
    private readonly IUnityContainer _container;

    public UnityDependencyResolver(IUnityContainer container) {
        _container = container;
    }

    public object GetService(Type serviceType) {
        return typeof(IController).IsAssignableFrom(serviceType) ||
            _container.IsRegistered(serviceType) ?
            _container.Resolve(serviceType) : null;
    }

    public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType) {
        return _container.ResolveAll(serviceType);
    }
}
```

I'd really appreciate it if someone could show me what i've done wrong. Thanks

Comment: Have you debugged the `GetService` call? It certainly looks like you could return null on the call in a non exceptional way.

Comment: Hi thanks, it turns out the call to _container.IsRegistered(serviceType) returns null. If i remove the conditional statement from the GetService method and wrap it in a try catch (returning null if an exception is thrown) it works fine but ideally i'd like to remove the try/catch as it seems a little hacky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i've run out of patience and decided to go for the Try/Catch approach i was initially trying to avoid. Here is my new Dependency Resolver:

```
public class UnityDependencyResolver : IDependencyResolver {
    private readonly IUnityContainer _container;

    public UnityDependencyResolver(IUnityContainer container) {
        _container = container;
    }

    public object GetService(Type serviceType) {
        try {
            return _container.Resolve(serviceType);
        } catch {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType) {
        try  {
            return _container.ResolveAll(serviceType);
        } catch {
            return new List<object>();
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Did you use your own BaseController?

Comment: I figured out I need to do more work in GetService in order to get my service resolved when I have the service defined in my controller.  here is what I did there. public object GetService(Type serviceType) {try{return (serviceType.BaseType == typeof(BaseController) || serviceType.BaseType == typeof(Controller))? _container.Resolve(serviceType):(_container.IsRegistered(serviceType) ?_container.Resolve(serviceType) : null);}catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //todo: log the error
                return null;
            }
        }

Comment: Hi thanks, i'll have a play around with your suggested solution aswell.